# Exception on Android 4.0 `android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode)`

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-networking

When I run this piece of code on Android 2.3.6, it works fine. On 4.0 I get a StrictMode exception. From some questions on SO, seems like you cant do network operations on the UI thread. But I am not doing any UI operation on the UI thread.

I am calling doBackground directly and not execute, since I need to check the return value of the doBackground. I guess the below should have worked.

What am I missing here ?

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    God.identityHash = (String) new SwitchServer((IActionBar) splashScreen,
                God.mCruiseOnServer, nameText, phoneNumberText)
                .doInBackground(null);

    if (!mIsBackButtonPressed && God.identityHash != null) {
        FlurryAgent.logEvent(God.TCACCEPTED_AND_REGISTERED);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
        SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(splashScreen,
            "Unable to save your details. Please try again.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        God.setTermsAndConditions(splashScreen, false);
    }
}
}, SPLASH_DURATION);
```

Edit : Strict mode is not enabled on the phone.

Comment: is that `AsyncTask` or something else, I really can't understand what are you trying to do here

Comment: Yes, I am not using AsyncTask in its "normal" way at this one place.

Comment: I suggest you to use AsyncTask to achieve the thing that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, [`StrictMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) is something you explicitly turned on from code, it is just a debugging aid, and should not be left on in production code.

Secondly, calling `.doInBackground` manually means running it on the UI thread. If you use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as intended, you get its return value as a parameter in `.onPostExecute`.

Comment: I am calling doInBackground in a handler runnable, silly question, but doesnt that take doInBackground OFF the UI thread ?

Comment: No, the message handler runs it (albeit delayed), which means the UI thread.