# Using boilerpipe in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, stack-trace, boilerpipe

Boilerpipe is a library that basically extracts the main content from a webpage. For news websites, it is especially hard to extract the content as the formatting differs from site to site. So I've tried to integrate the boilerpipe library - https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/wiki/QuickStart

As per the installing guide, I have added the following to my Java classpath - boilerpipe-VERSION.jar, nekohtml-1.9.13.jar and xerces-2.9.1.jar

**What I'm trying to do with boilerpipe and my application flow that involves it**

I have a list view where there are a list of articles. I've set up an **onItemClickListener** such that when you click on any of the items on the **listview**, it takes the **url** specific to that article and uses **boilerpipe** to extract the text from that article and starts a **new activity** where it is printed in **textview**.

**The Problem**

My application crashes once I click on one of the items in the list.
**a.** I'm not sure if the code I've written is correct, as I'm a beginner. Please excuse me for that. If it is incorrect, how can I fix it? I have a feeling it may be a problem with the url.
**b.** If I haven't installed boilerplate correctly, what is the correct way of doing it

**List Activity:**

```
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArticleActivity.class);

            // getting page url
            String page_url = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.page_url)).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), page_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(page_url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // NOTE: Use ArticleExtractor unless DefaultExtractor gives better results for you
            try {
                String text = null;
                text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
                in.putExtra("text", text);
            } catch (BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startActivity(in);              
    });
}
```

**Article Activity:**

```
public class ArticleActivity extends Activity{

Intent in = getIntent();
String text = in.getStringExtra("text");


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_view);

    TextView tv;

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.page_url);
    tv.setText(text);
    } 
}
```

**article_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Article Title -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#dc6800"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=1.0
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=GT-N8000
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:326)
at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.HTMLFetcher.fetch(HTMLFetcher.java:35)
at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:87)
at com.j.infographx.ListRSSItemsActivity$1.onItemClick(ListRSSItemsActivity.java:94)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1287)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3078)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4161)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this doesn't have anything to do with BoilerPlate, but rather the fact that you're making a network call on the main thread. I recommend you check out [this thread regarding the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

Answer (score 0):

i thing its common problem... u just use AsyncTask. see that....

[Exception on Android 4.0 `android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921252/exception-on-android-4-0-android-os-strictmodeandroidblockguardpolicy-onnetwor)

don't block main ui use child thread...