# Android Studio: Build error after adding boilerpipe library

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2, boilerpipe

I am trying to use [boilerpipe][1] for parsing text. I copied `boilerpipe-1.2.0.jar`, `nekohtml-1.9.13.jar` and `xerces-2.9.1.jar` to lib folder and added them as library. But when i try to run the project i get a huge error. Here is its end portion-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Here is my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pushpankar.reader"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/boilerpipe-1.2.0/lib/xerces-2.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/boilerpipe-1.2.0/lib/nekohtml-1.9.13.jar')
    compile files('libs/boilerpipe-1.2.0/boilerpipe-1.2.0.jar')
}
```

Here is the output with the --debug option

```
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:374)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:294)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:787)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1722)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:773)\n\t... 16 more\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004\n\tat com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.throwBadUtf8(CstString.java:172)\n\tat com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:143)\n\tat com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.\u003cinit\u003e(CstString.java:200)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)\n\t... 29 more\n","tool":"Dex"}
    13:53:36.360 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    13:53:36.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

Comment: Have you tried what the error suggests? `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`

Comment: It can be that these libraries don't fit for Android (too big or too resource expensive,...).

Comment: @pleft I tried the --debug option. I is also giving very similar error which is too large to paste here.

Comment: Is there any good alternative to it. @Bevor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088702/using-boilerpipe-in-android . He is able to use it.

Comment: @user3125971 Then there is another error (but always think about about that 'usual' libraries don't fit with Android in some cases). What about the stack trace. Post ther important part here.

Comment: I have uploaded the log on the pastebin. please see it.

Comment: This looks like a Java version incompatibility but probably pleft's answer will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your JDK version you are using?

You have to use the same Java version or greater than the one that was used to compile the external jars (boilerpipe).

**UPDATE:**

From the error log you posted it looks like the error is:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte`

and this error has been filled in the github issue tracking of the boilerpipe project: https://github.com/matanster/boilerpipe/issues/74

Comment: I am using openjdk 1.8

Comment: In Android (on the device) you can't choose a Java version.

Comment: @Bevor Of course, I mean what version is using the Android Studio to compile the application.

Comment: @user3125971 can you switch to oracle java 1.8 and set your gradle `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }`

Comment: Please check my updated answer. In the link provided, in the last comment there exist a link with the compiled `xerces.jar`

Comment: You are awesome @pleft